# Oracle SQL - Finding first record after specific date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with Oracle SQL and have encountered a problem.

I have one table **TableA** where I get the returndate for a vehicle.

I have another table **TableB** where I get the inspection dates for the vehicle. The table has a column called *id* where id = 2 means that the vehicle has been inspected. It is possible for the vehicle to be inspected many times

Is it someway possible to get the first inspection date after the return date?

It tried something like the following, but it seems way off. Any ideas?

```
select a.returndate, b.time as inspectdate
from tabel a
join tabelb b on a.vehicleid = b.vehicleid where b.id = 93
where a.vehicle= 011 and min(b.time) > a.returndate;
```

Comment: I would stop editing your query with more specifics. Instead explain additional criteria that might be important in (Edit:  ) style. After all we build our Query off from your base one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice use case for `CROSS APPLY`, if you have Oracle 12c:

```
select a.returndate, b.inspectdate
from tabela a
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT * FROM tabelb b 
              WHERE b.vehicleid = a.vehicleid
              AND   b.inspectdate > a.returndate
              ORDER BY b.inspectdate
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) b
where  a.vehicleid = 011
```

For each row in `tabela`, the `CROSS APPLY` will find the `tabelb` records that are later than the `returndate`, order them by `inspectdate` and give you the 1st one only.

This has the advantage over the answer by IT Alex in that it works without the limitation on `a.vehicleid`.  That is, you can run it for many vehicles at once (say, in a report or a summary screen).

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.returndate, b.inspectdate
from tabel a
join tabelb b on a.vehicleid = b.vehicleid
where a.vehicle= 011 
and   b.inspectdate > a.returndate
and   b.id = 93
order by b.inspectdate asc;
```

Grab the inspectdate(s) that are over returndate and then order them from oldest to newest. The first row will be the date that was the first inspection after the return.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this returns multiple rows. I am guessing I have to do a MIN(INSPECTDATE)